# Algebra of Vectors

Tags: geometry, vector-spaces

> Is it possible that there are $3$ vectors, $a, b, c$, such that $a + b + c = 0$ but $|a| = 1$, $|b| = 2$ and $|c| = 4$?

If yes why? and if no why?. I'm trying to get the solution since last $2$ days, so kindly help me out...

Answer (score 8):

This is not possible due to the [triangle inequality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangle_inequality). To be specific, if you add three vectors and obtain 0, that means, when they're attached at the end in sequence, they constitute a triangle. The triangle inequality states that one of the sides of a triangle can not be longer than the sum of the other two.

Comment: or $4=|c|=|-(a+b)|=|a+b|\leq |a|+|b|=1+2=3$

Comment: Yes, I see now. Thank you for the clarification.

Comment: $4=|c|=|-a-b|\le |a|+|b|=3$. Contradiction

Answer (score 2):

The triangle inequality for vectors says that $|x+y| \le |x|+|y|$ for all $x,y$. We also have $|\lambda x|=|\lambda|\cdot |x|$ for any number $\lambda$.

So, if $a+b+c=0$, then $c=-a-b = (-1)(a+b)$. Then,
$$|c|=|-1|\cdot |a+b|=|a+b|\le |a|+|b| $$
So, if $|a|=1$ and $|b|=2$, then $|c|\le 3$ and cannot be $4$.